# Python etree to markdown

Tags: python, html, markdown, lxml, elementtree

I am currently parsing a lxml.etree in python, but I am only extracting certain elements (simplifying the page to only certain data).

The problem I'm having is that some of the text is **bold** and I would like to keep it that way in the md, but I cannot find the way.

Here is an example:

```
<li id="id1">
"Normal text "
<nobr>bold</nobr>
.
</li>
```

which renders like

Normal text **bold**.

in html.

I tried doing `''.join(data[1].itertext())'` (data is that `lxml.etree._Element` from which I want to get the text), but it strips it down to `Normal text bold.`, thus not keeping the **bold**.

Comment: I found a partial solution, which is using `markdownify` and replacing the `<nobr>` tags to `<b>`, that seems to be working

Comment: The [nobr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr) (or non-breaking text tag) has nothing to do with bold. Its function is to prevent the text within from being wrapped to multiple lines. More importantly, it is nonstandard and its use is discouraged. If the HTML is rendering with the text in bold, then presumably some CSS is styling the `nobr` elements that way. This is some weird non-standard markup and won't easily convert to Markdown. Modifying the HTML to use standard tags would be the first step.